# How do I calibrate an AVR's RC oscillator using the UART?

Tags: avr, uart

I would like to set my AVR's OSCCAL for proper RS-232 communication using the other end's transmission as the calibration clock, without having to solder the RX pin to a timer pin. Is there firmware to do this?

---

**edit**
I wound up writing my own synchronization routine and soldering the RX pin to the ICP (input capture) unit. When the ICP pin changes, TIMER1's value is copied into a register and an interrupt fires.

The code uses an ADCPM-inspired search technique. OSCCAL is incremented or decremented by 1 initially. Each time OSCCAL needs to move in the same direction again it moves twice as far, when it switches direction it starts over at 1. http://code.google.com/p/pwmsign/source/browse/synch.c

All that trouble, and I discovered the perfect OSCCAL was only 1 off from the factory setting.

Comment: If you give me a link to the associated docs, I should be able to take a look tomorrow and help out.

Comment: what do you mean by 'proper UART communication'? you don't need clock synchronization between the AVR and the other end of the UART to make it work.  I guess maybe if your bit banging the UART on the AVR end which i find unlikely.

Comment: @Mark I mean the TX clock of the AVR has to match the RX clock of the PC within a few % and vice versa, not guaranteed without an XTAL.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly I'm looking for the Atmel-provided datasheet, AVR054: Run-time calibration of the internal RC oscillator. I think it could be adapted to PC-to-AVR communication without too much trouble...

Comment: Why is this an answer?

Comment: I am using an ATtiny2313 which does not have e.g. a PCINTn on the RX pin. So I think the answer is to use AVR054 and go ahead and solder RX to INT0.

Comment: No, I think you are miss-understanding.

Comment: @Kortuk I would be very happy to get another answer, but my answer to my own question is 'go ahead and solder two pins together and use AVR054'.

Comment: I was asking for links to your datasheet. I will write and answer when I confirm I am not misunderstanding. I do not think you need the cal feature at all.

Comment: @Kortuk the factory calibration was really close, but I didn't know until I wrote my own calibration routine! It probably would have worked fine without all the trouble.